# Using R's sapply to append Strings

Tags: r, loops, sapply

What I want to do is basically this:

```
words<-c("hello","what","how")
re<-c("I","say")
for(x in words){
        re<-c(re,x)
}
print(re)
[1] "I"     "say"   "hello" "what"  "how"
```

However, I'd like to replace the loop by sapply (because what I'm really trying to do is something more complicated that takes forever, and I want to switch to the parallel version of sapply once I get the function to do what I want).

Hoever, I cannot figure out how to implement this loop with sapply. What I tried was:

```
testfun<-function(x,res){
        res<-c(res,x)
        return(res)
}

words<-c("hello","what","how")
re<-c("I","say")

re<-sapply(words,testfun,res=re)

print(re)

     hello   what   how  
[1,] "I"     "I"    "I"  
[2,] "say"   "say"  "say"
[3,] "hello" "what" "how"
```

I can see why this is happening (it's applying the function to the original value of re each time rather than to the output from the previous iteration), but I don't know how to change it so that I get the output from the upper code.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `sapply` vectorizes the function to your specified objects, i.e. adds "hello", "want", and "how" respectively to `re`, so it is not suitable for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do `c(re, words)`? That gives the same result as your loop for me?

Comment: Well yeah, but like I said, what I'm really trying to do is much more complicated (involving rbinding dataframes instead of concatenating lists) and won't be solved with that - this is just a minimal working example to explain my problem...

Comment: Perhaps give an example with rbinding dataframes? I'm not quite making the conceptual leap here.